# How many Layouts can be nested in one Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android Developing. One of my Interview Question is "What is the limit of the nested layout" used in a single activity. And My Answer was "It can be any number that is required", probably that wasn't enough to satisfy the Question. Please let me know the exact answer if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a specific number across all devices, but the short answer is: until the depth of the call stack required to render it exceeds the maximum stack size and you get a `StackOverflowError`.  This varies by device and OS version - it tends to be smaller on older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite, until you run out of memory.  Of course the more you nest, the less efficient your rendering becomes, so you should be suspicious if your depth goes above 4 or so.  But there's no hardcoded limit.

Comment: Not quite true: it's limited by stack depth, not memory. At least on some versions, this is definitely hardcoded. Also a depth of 4+ is suuuuuper common, you don't need many FrameLayouts to get there.

Comment: That's not true. Android allows upto 10 level depth by default.

Comment: @DeepakVajpayee That's just wrong.  It allows infinite.  There is no check on the depth of layouts.  I've personally worked on (badly written) apps that used more than that.  They displayed just fine, although drawing performance sucked until I refactored it

Comment: @RyanMentley Stack depth *is* a form of memory.  You use up stack memory while performing the render recursively.  When you run out of stack memory (because the stack pointer crashes into unallocated memory or another segment) it throws an exception and crashes.